# Vocês acham que as perguntas inseridas na tag [inserir] estão mal classificadas?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Veja o conteúdo de [inserir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inserir). Me parece que boa parte das perguntas são na verdade [sql-insert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert). Concordam? Querem editar lá? Vai devagar... não precisa fazer tudo de uma vez, durante o dia não faça mais que umas 4 ou 5, a não ser que espace bem.

Algumas talvez sejam outro tipo de `insert`. O problema é que se manter uma *tag* `insert` ela certamente será bastante usada no lugar de [sql-insert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert). Vale mantê-la assim mesmo? Tem várias perguntas lá que não são sobre SQL. Mas teremos que lidar com o problema do uso errado o tempo todo.

Outras parecem que o fato de estar inserindo algo é circunstancial e não precisa de uma *tag* "inserir" para ajudar. Concordam? Ou tem exceções? Tem perguntas lá que merecem essa *tag* e não pode ser outra?

Minha ideia é matar essa *tag*. Não parece boa. Mas se tiver um bom argumento que mostre que tem algumas perguntas onde ela ajuda bem classificar de forma correta eu posso deixar.

Só dá para matar se tiver solução para todas perguntas, seja trocar de *tag* ou retirar onde não há nenhuma necessidade, mas não pode retirar forçadamente.

Está aberta a discussão.

Se alguém resolver tudo, favor avisar aqui para encerrar esse debate e considerar finalizado.

Comment: Acho que a tag é desnecessária, uma vez que por si só, não está relacionada a nada.

Comment: Acho que a tag sql-insert é necessária, este comando faz parte do CRUD, e muitas vezes ocorrem problemas quando vamos inserir um registro em uma tabela.

Comment: Depois de ver as 18 perguntas acho que  tag `inserir` pode ser retirada das perguntas não relacionadas com banco de dados.

Comment: @bigown Eu entendo que você não queira usar os "seus poderes" de forma que possa parecer abusiva, nesse sentido a ideia dos debates é boa e adequada, vamos ver se resulta.

Comment: @ramaral um pouco isso, um pouco porque eu tenho dúvidas. Se eu estivesse 100% eu até faria sem consulta, como já fiz em vários casos. Fora isso quero tentar conscientizar o pessoal (muita gente não pegou a época que era mais organizado) da importância de manter tudo bem classificado e que isso é um trabalho que se deve fazer sempre.

Comment: O termo "inserir" pode remover, na minha opinião. Acho que `insert` e `sql-insert` podem ficar pois são os termos mais apropriados porque fazem parte da linguagem SQL. Não são termos coloquiais.